# Unique backbone event buses that can also share global events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I want to have multiple unique event buses that also listen to global events. Here's what I want to see output:

```
global triggered on a by master
global triggered on b by master
search triggered on a by a
search triggered on b by b
```

Here's my code:

```
var master = Backbone.Events;
// when this is attached a listens to b and b listens to a
// when this isn't attached no one listens to the global event
// master.on('fake', function(){});
var a = $.extend({}, master);
var b = $.extend({}, master);

function respond(bus, event, by) {
    $('#log').append('<div><code>' + event + '</code> triggered on <code>' + bus + '</code> by <code>' + by + '</code></div>');
}
a.on('global', function (by) { respond('a', 'global', by); });
b.on('global', function (by) { respond('b', 'global', by); });

a.on('search', function (by) { respond('a', 'search', by); });
b.on('search', function (by) { respond('b', 'search', by); });

master.trigger('global', 'master');
a.trigger('search', 'a');
b.trigger('search', 'b');
```

Here's a [fiddle *without* `master.on`](http://jsfiddle.net/HE28x/) and here's [one *with* `master.on`](http://jsfiddle.net/HE28x/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen because you are extending from the same master object and so you are registering events on all the istances.

I'm proposing this solution based on two different channels:

```
var master = Backbone.Events;
var Bus = (function(){    
    function Bus(){
        this.vent = {};
        _.extend(this.vent, Backbone.Events);
        this.globalVent = master;
    }
    return Bus;
})();

var a = new Bus();
var b = new Bus();

function respond(bus, event, by) {
    $('#log').append('<div><code>' + event + '</code> triggered on <code>' + bus + '</code> by <code>' + by + '</code></div>');
}
a.globalVent.on('global', function (by) {
    respond('a', 'global', by);
});
b.globalVent.on('global', function (by) {
    respond('b', 'global', by);
});

a.vent.on('search', function (by) {
    respond('a', 'search', by);
});
b.vent.on('search', function (by) {
    respond('b', 'search', by);
});

master.trigger('global', 'master');
a.vent.trigger('search', 'a');
b.vent.trigger('search', 'b');
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HE28x/3/)